# Linux: No output when running a (working) command in a .sh script

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I want to get the output from a program in Linux, and I put this into a .sh file:

```
wine Blockland.exe ptlaaxobimwroe -dedicated -port 30100 > consoleLog.txt
```

It executed the program, but created a blank file. **This command always works when directly executed in a Terminal window**. So why isn't it printing the output to the file when in a .sh script?

Comment: You are running a DOS console application, which does not necessarily write to stdout or stderr, but it writes to the "console". It's nearly impossible to capture the "console" output reliably.  The only tool that I have ever seen that is able to capture console output is `expect` by Don Libes, and that does all sorts of hacks.

Comment: Or try executing in a `script` session.

Answer (score 1):

Possibly because it prints its output to the `stderr` stream, not to `stdout`. Try appending `2>&1` to the end of command (after consoleLog.txt), or just use `&>` instead of `>`.

Answer (score 0):

redirect stdout with exec:

```
#!/bin/sh
#Example script
exec > consoleLog.txt
wine Blockland.exe ptlaaxobimwroe -dedicated -port 30100
```